# mod_rewrite rule should be matching, but isn't

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, regex

I've only started editing rewrite rules a few days ago, before now I'd copy and paste them for each case. I've written a rule which as far as I can tell*, should be matching but isn't

```
RewriteRule ^/store/(([A-Za-z]+)-Clocks+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.asp($) /store/product/$3? [NC,R=301,L]`
```

I want this to be able to match `domain.com/store/Alarm-Clocks/maf09r.asp` and redirect to `domain.com/store/product/maf09r/` All I can see in my error log is this:

```
[Fri May 31 12:08:17 2013] [error] [client IP] File does not exist: /home/user/store/Alarm-Clocks
[Fri May 31 12:09:18 2013] [error] [client IP] File does not exist: /home/user/store/Mantel-Clocks
```

where `/home/user/` is the website root

Is there anything glaringly obvious which I've done wrong?

*I've tested with both [this](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and [this](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: Isn't the group you want to match `$3` not `$4` ?

Comment: My mistake, that's still in from when I was trying to get it working, the error is still the same though, I'll edit that now

Comment: also, what does ($) match against, if you want the end of the line, $ should be fine by itself..

Comment: it should be matching the `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` part before .asp but with my severe lack of knowledge, it may not be doing that - Edit, sorry, I misread the question, I've only modified this line by piecing together other rules and trying to learn from them

Comment: It would be matching, uh.. dunno. if you just want to match .asp at the end of the line `\.asp$`

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine on` in your config before this rule and is this rule inside a `<Directory>` block or a `.htaccess` file?